# Perfect Forward secrecy in TLS session

Tags: tls

I am looking at packet captures of perfect forward secrecy for cipher "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256". Per definition of PFS, after initial client and server hellos exchanged, both sides must come up with public-private key pairs and they share the new public keys. In packet capture, i am seeing client is sending its public key in very next message (under "EC-Diffie-Hellman Client Params" header) but server doesn't (instead server is sending new session ticket). How does server sends its new public key to client?

Comment: Server sends its ephemeral key (and parameter info, usually a small number for one of the standard "named" curves) in ServerKeyExchange *after* (Server)Cert and *before* ServerHelloDone and thus *before* (Client)Cert or ClientKeyExchange. Look at your capture again; some capture display formats don't have room for details of multiple TLS messages contained in one frame, or frame group, especially if they are also combined in one TLS *record*. Make sure you look at each record *and* each message. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work for many details.

Answer (score 1):

From [RFC 4492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492), section 2.2:

> The server sends its ephemeral ECDH public key and a specification of
> the corresponding curve in the *ServerKeyExchange* message.  These
> parameters MUST be signed with ECDSA using the private key
> corresponding to the public key in the server's Certificate.
>
> The client generates an ECDH key pair on the same curve as the
> server's ephemeral ECDH key and sends its public key in the
> *ClientKeyExchange* message.

Further, in sections 5.4 and 5.7 you can find their structure.

Comment: Hi Dave and Zakjan, thanks for your responses. I looked again at my pcaps and yes in Server Key exchange message (before server hello done), i can see something with length of 329 bytes but i don't see it with label like key etc (the way i am seeing it in client key exchange message). Is this expected? Do i have to enable/disable something in Wireshark so it interpret it correctly? (By the way i am checking by going to https://mail.google.com). Thanks

Comment: I can see ECDH server params in Wireshark, with no special setting necessary. Check if you have the latest version. http://imgur.com/tWPunSo